# Variants of stream closing pattern in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, resource-management

I often see the following pattern both in Java documentation and in other people's code when dealing with streams:

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
  fis = new FileInputStream("some.file");
  // do something useful with fis
} finally {
  if (fis != null) {
    fis.close();
  }
}
```

However I personally prefer a different pattern:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("some.file");
try {
  // do something useful with fis
} finally {
  fis.close();
}
```

I like the brevity of the latter and I think it's correct. But am I right about correctness? Is there an objective reason to prefer one over another?

### Update

Even if I write the examples pretty much how I would write such code in real life my pattern is still more concise. Compare the documentation approach:

```
public Object processFile(String fn) throws MyException {
  FileInputStream fis = null;
  try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(fn);
    return new Object(); // somehow derived from fis
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    throw new MySubExceptionForNotFound(e);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new MySubExceptionForIoError(e);
  } finally {
    if (fis != null) {
      IOUtils.closeQuietly(fis);
    }
  }
}
```

with my approach:

```
public Object processFile(String fn) throws MyException {
  try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fn);
    try {
      return new Object(); // somehow derived from fis
    } finally {
      IOUtils.closeQuietly(fis);
    }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    throw new MySubExceptionForNotFound(e);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new MySubExceptionForIoError(e);
  }
}
```

Mine is one line shorter! :D

Interestingly my code does not change if you decide to use `fis.close()` instead of `IOUtils.closeQuietly()` while the "official" code will grow another 4 lines.

Comment: Or even better: try with resources

Comment: @assylias yeah it's the right thing to do, thanks. But a) it only works in Java 7, and b) the question stands: why obviously inferior pattern is used throughout the documentation? One would think there ought to be a reason...

Answer (score 1):

The second example that you have posted would not try/catch the possible errors that `... = new FileInputStream("...");` will return if it fails loading the file.
In the first example though you automatically also catch the errors that the `FileInputStream` gives.

I would personally go with the first one to have better error handling.

Comment: If `new FileInputStream()` throws then `fis` remains `null` hence there is nothing to close. The first example in my question would check `fis` and skip `close()`. The second example wouldn't even enter the `try`. The net result would be exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks, but my point was that FileInputStream DOES throw and exception if something goes wrong, so you can also make checks on that.

Answer (score 1):

The second example does not compile unless you throw the exception from the method, because `FileNotFoundException` is a checked exception.

```
Compile.java:5: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("some.file");
```

The first example also does not compile, because you are missing the appropriate `catch` block. Here is a compiling example.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Compile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("some.file");
            // do something useful with fis

            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
        }
        finally {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The constructor can throw an unchecked SecurityException at runtime too if there's a security manager configured.

Comment: @TrevorTippins, That is certainly true, but that is not a checked exception, and I am only addressing compile-time errors.

Comment: My code snippets weren't supposed to be full working Java applications. And they weren't supposed to catch all exceptions. You don't always catch all exceptions, do you? Just add a `throws IOException` clause to your `main()` declaration and both my examples will compile as is.

Comment: @SnakE, Most real applications I see do not have `main` throwing Exceptions up to the user.

Comment: @merlin2011, most real application don't process files in their `main()`. Also I prefer to throw unhandled exceptions from main() when an application is supposed to be run as an unattended sub-process. This way exceptions can be logged by the parent.

Comment: @SnakE, That is a fair point. I guess it depends on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("some.file")) {
    // some code here
}
```

---

To answer the question of why the recommended pattern is the way it is, consider the fact that `new FileInputStream(String)` throws a checked exception that you should probably catch; The

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream("somefile.txt");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    return false;
} finally {
    if (fis != null) {
        fis.close();
    }
}
```

allows you to handle it in the same try/catch block as your other file-related exceptions. This has brevity and reduced nesting advantages over the following:

```
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("some.file");
    try {
        // do something useful with fis
    } finally {
        fis.close();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    return false;
}
```

And if you're not catching the exception and just letting it propagate, then your suggestion is cleaner - however given the heavy use of checked exceptions in the IO libraries (including from class constructors), catching and handling an exception is common enough, and I think it makes sense to have just one pattern for tutorial purposes instead of showing someone a slightly different pattern each time.

Comment: It is polite to attribute this idea to assylias if you're going to write it into an answer.

Comment: A good one but it only works in Java 7 which is not always available. And it does not answer the question: why a certain pattern is used all over the official documentation when there is a better one?

Comment: @SnakE See my updated answer for a possible reasoning; merlin2011: assylias' comment was not posted when I started writing my answer, and was not the source of inspiration for mine o.o

Comment: @DarthAndroid In the same vein I might argue that `fis.close()` also throws a checked exception that you should* probably catch. Add that to both snippets and see which has more brevity and readability. *Arguably you shouldn't but you won't see such a recommendation in official documentation.